# Are there turnkey services for simple usability testing of mobile apps, especially iOS?

Tags: mobile, usability-testing, ios

For websites, usertesting and trymyui and others are setup to do quick user testing. Are there similar services for mobile applications?

Comment: Surely a quick Google search will tell you this...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mob4hire.com/

> Mob4Hire is an online community of mobile device users paid to help application developers, advertisers, and content publishers with research, develop and pre-test anything mobile.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this article: http://webdesignledger.com/tools/7-useful-tools-for-mobile-website-testing

Also, this one is not really quick, but pretty nice otherwise:

[Mobile Usability Testing Tip: Recording from Two Webcams](http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2010/10/05/mobile-usability-testing-tip-recording-from-two-webcams/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+90percentofeverything%2Ffeed+%2890+Percent+of+Everything+%29) -- [(More info in a second post)](http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2010/11/15/more-mobile-usability-testing-sleds/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+90percentofeverything%2Ffeed+%2890+Percent+of+Everything+%29)

Answer (score 0):

UserTesting now does testing for mobile apps: http://www.usertesting.com/mobile.  They send their testers a webcam to provide an overhead view of their device.  The disadvantage is that the device has to be flat on a table, or close to it, so you might not see users interact with their devices in quite the same way as they might in real life.

Here's a Nielsen Norman Group article (2013) about mobile testing techniques if you want to do these studies on your own without a service like UserTesting: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-usability-testing/.